# Android onBackPressed dont work when DrawerLayout is opened

Tags: android

in appliaction i'm using DrawerLayout to have Sliding menu, i want to override `onBackPressed` to close DrawerLayout if is opend, or close from application, but `onBackPressed` dont work when DrawerLayout is opend, i must be close that and try again to press back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(UI.slide_menu)) {
        mDrawerState = false;
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(UI.slide_menu);
    }
    if (G.back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(G.context, R.string.press_once_again_to_exit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    G.back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
    {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
```

Comment: my problem is `onBackPressed` dont work when mDrawerLayout is opend

Comment: Rishad, please add some text to this answer explaining what your code does and how it solves the problem.  Solutions with just code blobs aren't usually very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working for me onBackPressed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```